# Checkout page phone number validation

Tags: magento2, module, onepage-checkout, custom, validation

I am trying to give US format phone number validation in onepage checkout page 
This is the layout checkout_index_index.xml that i created in my custom module. I know how to make i work by editing the core module (which is a strict no no when it comes to magento), Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong .

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlockname="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- Your customization will be here -->
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <!--Validation for US phone number format-->
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="phoneUS" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">For delivery questions.</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I tried doing this by copying the entire checkout_index_index.xml page into my custom module ,which worked partially, because when i did that the shipping price disappeared.

i found this [magento doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html) but didnt fully understand it.

Any help would be appretiated

Comment: Have you tried to just change the description `translate` attribute like `For delivery questions. 123` to be sure that your rewrite is working? Are you also cleaning your cache?

Comment: Yes i tried editing the description to see if it was working. And ofcource cleared the cache. Didn't work

Comment: Can you show the path were you are copying `checkout_index_index.xml` please?

Comment: app/code/myname/checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

Answer (score 5):

Vendor/Module/registration.php & put below code.

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

add the module.xml file in Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml & put below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

Create di.xml file in  Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml & put below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="validate_telephone_checkout_layoutprocessor" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type> 
</config>
```

Now, create LayoutProcessor.php in Vendor\Module\Plugin\LayoutProcessor & put below code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class LayoutProcessor
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']
        )) {

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']
            ['telephone']['validation'] = ['required-entry' => true, "validate-number"=>true, "min_text_length" =>10, "max_text_length" =>  10 ];
        }

         /* config: checkout/options/display_billing_address_on = payment_method */
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
        )) {
            foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                     ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) {
                    /* telephone */
                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                    ['telephone']['validation'] = ['required-entry' => true,"validate-number"=>true, "min_text_length" =>10, "max_text_length" =>  10 ];
            }
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

**This will validate phone number on checkout**

Comment: how can I test phone to match custom regex?